# body.clear() and body.insertFileFromBase64() not working as expected

Tags: ms-word, office-js

I have the requirement in which I need to clear/remove the existing content from a Word document and then insert new Base 64 encoded document.

The following is a code snippet where I'm first clearing the document `body` and then inserting the new document.

Also, If I comment the `body.clear()` then `InsertLocation.start` and `InsertLocation.end` is working fine. `InsertLocation.replace` does not work in regardless of calling `body.clear()` or not.

It also does not clear some items such as water marks, the header, or the footer.

I'm expecting that `body.clear()` should result a document which is same as a new blank document.

```js
showDocumentInWord(documentData, docName) {
    let self = this;
    window.Word.run(function (context) {
            let body = context.document.body;
            body.clear();
            body.insertFileFromBase64(documentData, 
                window.Word.InsertLocation.replace);
            return context.sync().then(function () {
                // Show success message here 
            });
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            if (error instanceof window.OfficeExtension.Error) {
                // console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are clearing the document body, you should use `"start"` rather than `"replace"` for the insertion location.

As for the header and footer, your code is only targeting `document.body`. In order to clear the header and footer of the document you will need to specifically clear those sections:

```js
return Word.run(function (context) {
    let sections = context.document.sections;
    sections.load();
    return context.sync()
        .then(function () {
            sections.items.forEach(function (section) {
                // Clear the Body
                section.body.clear();

                // Clear any Headers
                section.getHeader('primary').clear();
                section.getHeader('firstPage').clear();
                section.getHeader('evenPages').clear();

                // Clear any Footers
                section.getFooter('primary').clear();
                section.getFooter('firstPage').clear();
                section.getFooter('evenPages').clear();
            });                
        });        
});
```

You may also want to take a look at the beta release of [Word JavaScript API 1.4](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/tree/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec). Version 1.4 adds a [`createDocument(base64File: string)`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec/reference/word/application.md#createdocumentbase64file-string) method that allows you to create an entirely new document based on a `base64File`. It also adds an [`document.open()`](https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/WordJs_1.4_OpenSpec/reference/word/document.md#open) method that lets you open up the document object you created using `createDocument`.

Comment: Above solution is working on the word desktop application but on word online it's giving the following exception/Error.
Error: {"name":"OfficeExtension.Error","code":"NotAllowed","message":"The action isn’t supported in Word Online. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.","traceMessages":[],"innerError":null,"debugInfo":{"code":"NotAllowed","message":"The action isn’t supported in Word Online. Check the OfficeExtension.Error.debugInfo for more information.","errorLocation":"Body.clear"}}

Comment: Word Online doesn't support some features like watermarks. It is likely that it ran into an issue because there was content it didn't know what to do with. Could you provide a link to an example document that is failing in Word Online but not on the desktop? That would help with tracking down exactly what is going on here.

Answer (score 0):

@Chandan -- I'm unable to reproduce the error that you've described in the comment on @Marc_LaFleur's answer. Here's a complete code snippet for you:

```
function clearDocumentThenUpdateDocument() {
    return Word.run(function (context) {

        var sections = context.document.sections;
        sections.load();
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
               // Clear document contents (body, header, footer).
                sections.items.forEach(function (section) {
                    // Clear the Body.
                    section.body.clear();

                    // Clear any Headers.
                    section.getHeader('primary').clear();
                    section.getHeader('firstPage').clear();
                    section.getHeader('evenPages').clear();

                    // Clear any Footers.
                    section.getFooter('primary').clear();
                    section.getFooter('firstPage').clear();
                    section.getFooter('evenPages').clear();
                });

                var documentData = "UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQCKe3jjqQEAAJQIAAATAAgCW0NvbnRlbnRfVHlwZXNdLnhtbCCiBAIooAAC AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAC0 lk1PwzAMhu9I/IcqV7Rm44AQWseBjyMgAT8gJO5WrflQ7AH797jrWiE01o7RS6XU9vu8tdOm0+tP WybvELHwLhOTdCwScNqbws0z8fpyP7oUCZJyRpXeQSbWgOJ6dnoyfVkHwISrHWZiQRSupES9AKsw 9QEcR3IfrSJexrkMSi/VHOT5eHwhtXcEjkZUaYjZ9BZytSopufvk27WTCCWK5KZOrFiZUCGUhVbE cfnuzA/KaEtIuXKTg4si4BknCLmTUEV+B2zrHrk1sTCQPKlID8pylvzw0Ujj9cpyZbpfZodPn+eF hra+UgvRa0DkntsybSNWFa7x/6sPpHUJ+P8uat1uPBBxwRAGtsqdFj7g7XkwF9/EO43k3pPzNMQ0 WulOE+DMQB4a5U4LC1AG4uT/HdTCveYwCL8W7sFnnnorYQgHW+k+bwU03zqUpHAZlOu1LWxjo9r8 rUarcCD5+6rPSHbTO6HEBw/U1+MHv5HZh+TMp+gD8kEW/zDl5qSqqkc83wCRiv2dbYksffTzbdpq wBzK1iskb4/G1zI74HLzTzH7AgAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEApwT9ziQBAAB4AwAACwAIAl9y ZWxzLy5yZWxzIKIEAiigAAIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAKzTy2rDMBAF0H2h/yC0j2WnD0qJnU0pZFeK+wFTaeyYRBohTZrk76uk D+KQuoVmKenqcjzCk+nGLsUbhtiRK2WR5VKg02Q615bypX4c3UkRGZyBJTks5RajnFaXF5NnXAKn S3He+ShSi4ulnDP7e6WinqOFmJFHl04aChY4LUOrPOgFtKjGeX6rwmGHrHqdYmZKGWbmSop66/F/ 3coigwEGpSngyId0O3CXvkXUEFrkUhrST2k77hNZapbqNGj8A8h2OlCkhjNNVlHTdHpHKYojyhpf ccPodhNniAsP7tCxpmB6mai+U0Os4u9z+rA9kF5ZdHxqXP3EEc58bg9pbs6p0avIZH95tX1miHR9 TtL+dQyaYRR4/yVSvf+legcAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAM/a/yolAQAAOQUAABwACAF3b3Jk L19yZWxzL2RvY3VtZW50LnhtbC5yZWxzIKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAArJTLTsMwEEX3SPxD5D1xUqA8VKcbhNQthA9w48lDJOPIHh75e0yrBhcqi4WXcy3fe3TH8mr9 OfTJOxjbaRQsTzOWAFZaddgI9lI+XtyyxJJEJXuNINgElq2L87PVE/SS3CXbdqNNnAtawVqi8Z5z W7UwSJvqEdCd1NoMktxoGj7K6lU2wBdZtuTG92DFkWeyUYKZjXL55TTCf7x1XXcVPOjqbQCkExG8 1kil3PbgTKVpgASbpdS5MX4a4jImxAdsn4HINWx/MDwxBHITtw1NYPwqvuc8lL+ImW//tHBQQgh5 VASaevABdnMofhkzvgWp/A3s5+AGrmPmAyp0O/cKOCghhKvYj/AXwyyFIO5iQpC76/0Ju3Evzrvg Rx9e8QUAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAIvpQZkNAwAAzwoAABEAAAB3b3JkL2RvY3VtZW50Lnht bKSW3W/aMBDA3yftf8jy3joJJLCoUG1AOx62VaXTHifjOCQiji3bQNlfv3M+CFW6KqQvJvb5fvfh 8+Gb22eWWXsqVcrzie1eO7ZFc8KjNN9M7F9Pd1dj21Ia5xHOeE4n9pEq+3b68cPNIYw42TGaawsQ uQoPgkzsRGsRIqRIQhlW1ywlkise62vCGeJxnBKKDlxGyHNcp/gSkhOqFNib4XyPlV3hyHM3WiTx AZQNcIhIgqWmzw3DvRjio89o3AZ5PUAQoee2UYOLUQEyXrVAw14g8KpF8vuRXgku6Efy2qRRP9Kg TRr3I7XKibULnAuagzDmkmENU7lBDMvtTlwBWGCdrtMs1UdgOkGNwWm+7eERaJ0IbBBdTBghxiOa DaKawif2TuZhpX910jeuh6V+9VNryC7xlyrzqjkUkSNJM8gFz1WSitMNZ31pIExqyP6tIPYsq/cd hNvxuvyvPc3LVDbALu5X+WdZ6fnbRNfpcCIGcdLo4sJLm7UnDKqwMdwrNWfJdTs2kBrgtQABSTuW dM0oswnxgOYZR9HLMH6NUUfWXPWD2LyvWu4l34mGlr6Ptmzu/sH8C1/Aqqru/Cao9zmzSrCAlsBI uNzkXOJ1Bh5BDVlQBlZxAmaEU7HMpbOn8FRY8+hofgVIhqHAEi/htJ3ZInD8u4FdrEKj1WZ1GMwD Z/TFh9UQniXRI2x05ne+489OS3Ma412mjWSx8L2FV1iRZtDTp2/LlbVc3SAzMWOxvuZ8a1rzSkNP B44pN8cAc8zA/z/3/CsmWxud713k0WlnISgtmESGSmACekJSReWe2lPr6dvC+rH4bc1/zj69MA6j MIqKEv0gXwnLCBOKIyofaUwlPMAghaE+CjAQlaHaliwckcsoKH2JOdfdFEalgtis/sIuaBqu5w2L 2BP49sfDKjqx+Y6Ne5pDb3OH5RaZbhLdTNdca86aeUbjM2kZxMQeecW0dPE03ex0Ma3MEZ4pWK0S afYUy/CsvJemeMIszelDqgl4OQgKKaqTWHyWVYWal+j0HwAAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAFAY VxeGAgAAogoAABIAAAB3b3JkL2Zvb3Rub3Rlcy54bWzUls1ymzAQx++d6TswutsCbGyHsZ1p46ST WyZpH0ARwmaCPkYSJn77rsBgt7gZTE71AYyk/0+7q92F5e07z7090yaTYoWCsY88JqhMMrFdoV8/ H0YL5BlLREJyKdgKHZhBt+uvX5ZlnEpphbTMeMAQJi4VXaGdtSrG2NAd48SMeUa1NDK1Yyo5lmma UYZLqRMc+oFf/VNaUmYMbHhHxJ4YdMTR9360RJMSxA44xXRHtGXvJ0ZwNSTCN3jRBYUDQOBhGHRR k6tRM+ys6oCmg0BgVYcUDSNdcG42jBR2SfNhpEmXtBhG6qQT7ya4VEzAZCo1JxYe9RZzot8KNQKw IjZ7zfLMHoDpzxoMycTbAItA1RL4JLmaMMdcJiyfJA1FrlChRXzUj1q9Mz2u9cdbo9B9/K8lG0kL zoStPMea5RALKcwuU22F86E0mNw1kP1HTux53qwrVdCzXP7VnjZ1KE/APuYf48/z2vKPiYHf40Qc olX0MeHPPRtLOGThaeNBoTkLbtCzgTSAsAOY0axnSjeMOprgDyjPOIZdh4kajDnwU6mXavu5bPmh ZaFOtOxztMdT7ZfuNXwF65h155VgPmfMy44oaAmcxo9bITV5zcEiyCEP0sCrTsBd4VQ8V3Roffat 4JWxPShYbpgimlipEQy5kx8F1UIF0mns5h5hMFj4/vzhPkLVKHRi60bnx5+TwodL8rxCvr+4Cb9/ C9uhDUtJkdvuzJMb2jxEfnRXb/ik3c0oQsE1WERSy6DP+U6QZy7Y4bR9eC6cr6SwEuH1ErfymtH4 VE/pekF1bfy/GAsqhc1EUTXIl7/j4l8Iy+w+imabcPp/hOWiex+F6OzBrH8DAAD//wMAUEsDBBQA BgAIAAAAIQDY5o5eRwIAABIJAAAQAAAAd29yZC9mb290ZXIxLnhtbKSWX2+bMBDA3yftOyC/JwYS 0hSFVFpYpjxMrdruYY8umICK/8h2QvLtd0CATGwVoS8Gzr6f7853h1cPJ5ZbR6p0JniAnKmNLMoj EWd8H6Bfr9vJElnaEB6TXHAaoDPV6GH99cuq8BOjLNDm2i9kFKDUGOljrKOUMqKnLIuU0CIx00gw LJIkiyguhIqxazt29SaViKjWsNWG8CPR6IKLTsNosSIFKJfAOY5Sogw9dQznZoiH7/GyD3JHgMBD 1+mjZjejFri0qgeajwKBVT2SN470D+cW40hun3Q3jjTrk5bjSL10Yv0EF5JymEyEYsTAp9pjRtT7 QU4ALInJ3rI8M2dg2osGQzL+PsIi0GoJbBbfTLjDTMQ0n8UNRQTooLh/0Z+0+qXpfq1/eTQaaoj/ tUooogOj3FSeY0VziIXgOs1kW+FsLA0m0wZy/MiJI8ubdYV0BpbL/9pTWIeyAw4x/xJ/lteWf0x0 7AEnUiJajSEm/L1nYwmDLOw2HhWaq+A6AxtIA3B7gEWUDUzphlFHE/wBzSuOprdhvAajz6wr9ULu P5ctP5Q4yI6WfY6262q/KH/AN7AuWXddCfpzxrykREJLYJG/23OhyFsOFkEOWZAGVnUC5QinYpVF h9ZwS5AgmfuSKLKDU/bcxbf7jQMNsZRCgzWl1Pbm2zB0ZiD14SYSP4PIDree7W1aUUgTcsjN1UxF f1LV48Wcc9jbP5I8QFshDFUIr1e4XVENZv3z9/bx8fX7czljqnlVr6pGuNGs/wAAAP//AwBQSwME FAAGAAgAAAAhAE2Cyn1JAgAAEgkAABAAAAB3b3JkL2hlYWRlcjEueG1spJZLj5swEIDvlfofkO+J ISGPopBVumy6OVSqdttDj17jBLT4IdsJyb/vACGkol0RcjEw4/k8M54xXjwceeYcmDapFCHyhi5y mKAyTsUuRL9+rgdz5BhLREwyKViITsygh+XnT4s8SGLtgLUwQa5oiBJrVYCxoQnjxAx5SrU0cmuH VHIst9uUMpxLHeOR67nlm9KSMmNgqUciDsSgM44eu9FiTXIwLoA+pgnRlh0bhnczZIK/4HkbNOoB gghHXhs1vhk1xYVXLZDfCwRetUiTfqR/BDftRxq1SbN+pHGbNO9HapUTbxe4VEyAcis1JxY+9Q5z ot/3agBgRWz6lmapPQHTndYYkor3Hh6B1YXAx/HNhBnmMmbZOK4pMkR7LYKz/eBiX7geVPbnR22h u8RfmUSS7jkTtowca5ZBLqQwSaouHc770kCZ1JDDR0EceFbPy5XXsV3+dzxFVSobYBf3z/nnWeX5 x0TP7bAjBeJi0cWFv9esPeFQhc3CvVJzlVyv4wFSA0YtwJSmHUu6ZlTZhHjA8opj2G2YSY0xJ960 eq5291XLNy33qqGl99E2Te/nxQ/4Bta56q47wdznzGtCFBwJnAabnZCavGXgEdSQA2XglDtQjLAr TtF0aAm3BAUSP1BEkw3s8thfzWeT6BGVUjhgbSH1/annrr+uQBrATSR+CZHrRuuJOykmVqKIbck+ s1eakv5Dl49Xe8pg7eBAshA9MxIzjfBygS8zysEuv/9+flpFTy+FxpZ6Xc0qR7jRLP8AAAD//wMA UEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQD8BTPJhgIAAJwKAAARAAAAd29yZC9lbmRub3Rlcy54bWzUlttu4jAQhu9X 2neIck+dBAI0Aqq2qKveVe3uA7iOAavxQbZDytvvmJzYDVuFcLVc5GB7Ps/8nhmyuPvkmben2jAp ln54E/geFUSmTGyX/q+fT6O57xmLRYozKejSP1Dj362+f1sUCRWpkJYaDxDCJIUiS39nrUoQMmRH OTY3nBEtjdzYGyI5kpsNIxQVUqcoCsLg+KS0JNQY2O8Riz02foUjn/1oqcYFGDvgBJEd1pZ+tozw YkiMbtG8C4oGgCDCKOyixhejpsh51QFNBoHAqw4pHkY6E9x0GCnqkmbDSOMuaT6M1Ekn3k1wqaiA yY3UHFt41VvEsf7I1QjAClv2zjJmD8AMpjUGM/ExwCOwagh8nF5MmCEuU5qN05oil36uRVLZjxp7 53pS2le32kL3ib80WUuScyrsMXKkaQZaSGF2TDUVzofSYHJXQ/ZfBbHnWb2uUGHPcvlXe1qXUrbA Pu5X+vOs9PxrYhj0OBGHaCz6uPDnnrUnHLKw3XiQNCfihj0bSA2IOoApYT1TumaUakI8YHnCMfQy TFxjzIG3pV6o7XXZ8kPLXLU0dh3tua39wv0LX8Cqsu60Esx1zrztsIKWwEnyvBVS4/cMPIIc8iAN vOMJuCuciueKzl+1nwpekdiDgtWGKqyxldqHIXfwo/C4ToHlJHFzzzA4DifhPLqHTxI3Co3YutFZ 9XOm8NmSvi79IJjfRg/3UTO0phucZ7Y78+KG1k9xED+WG75odzMKE4gMFuGNpdDm3J5JxpzW0aR5 ec1dqDi30kerBWrMS0YdUzmlywXHaxX+OSWIFJaJ/Ngd3/5WJTgjyiy+v32IH+P/Q5Sz4X0hUPts Vr8BAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQB/AYygwAAAABwBAAArAAAAd29yZC93ZWJleHRlbnNpb25z L19yZWxzL3Rhc2twYW5lcy54bWwucmVsc2TPwWrDMAwG4Huh72B0XxTvMEqJk1uh19E9gOsoiWls Gcts7dvPvTX0KIn/Q3833MOqfimL52hANy0oio5HH2cDP5fTxwGUFBtHu3IkAw8SGPr9rvum1ZYa ksUnUVWJYmApJR0RxS0UrDScKNbLxDnYUsc8Y7LuZmfCz7b9wvxqQL8x1Xk0kM+jBnV5JHqzg3eZ hafSOA7I0+TdU9V6q+IfXeleKD4LVsrmmYqB161u6o+AfYebTv0/AAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAA ACEAR9g01DIBAAAtAgAAJAAAAHdvcmQvd2ViZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy93ZWJleHRlbnNpb24xLnhtbJxR 0UrDMBR9F/yHkvc2SVvLNtaOarc3EXQDX7P2dg20NyWJbkP8d9PZwYbig4/n5p5zz8mZLw5d672D NlJhSnjAiAdYqkriLiWb9cqfEM9YgZVoFUJKjmDIIru9me9htoctHCzgwPWcDho3SkljbT+j1JQN dMIEnSy1Mqq2Qak6qupalkAvqeYK0ZBxRjknnqxS8sE4T3KWxD5PHmI/nvLcz4v73C/u2DKOwukq SqJPkg12NNSgnXk4MfeCsziasEkSksuALmIQDpmUdl4B/c3LiNbH3k2eHpevhJ4ERWtBo7DwfFY2 /z50tfXLOfrHvV6rHrSVYL59bSUO/YzIoOhNo+zYgP5RgCOje6uV7oR1UO/GFgpVvnWA1n05S6iG Vtihjkb25mzpspnsCwAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAtvRnmNIGAADJIAAAFQAAAHdvcmQvdGhl bWUvdGhlbWUxLnhtbOxZS4sbRxC+B/IfhrnLes3oYaw10kjya9c23rWDj71Sa6atnmnR3dq1MIZg n3IJBJyQQwy55RBCDDHE5JIfY7BJnB+R6h5JMy31xI9dgwm7glU/vqr+uqq6ujRz4eL9mDpHmAvC ko5bPVdxHZyM2JgkYce9fTAstVxHSJSMEWUJ7rgLLNyLO59/dgGdlxGOsQPyiTiPOm4k5ex8uSxG MIzEOTbDCcxNGI+RhC4Py2OOjkFvTMu1SqVRjhFJXCdBMai9MZmQEXYOlEp3Z6V8QOFfIoUaGFG+ r1RjQ0Jjx9Oq+hILEVDuHCHacWGdMTs+wPel61AkJEx03Ir+c8s7F8prISoLZHNyQ/23lFsKjKc1 LcfDw7Wg5/leo7vWrwFUbuMGzUFj0Fjr0wA0GsFOUy6mzmYt8JbYHChtWnT3m/161cDn9Ne38F1f fQy8BqVNbws/HAaZDXOgtOlv4f1eu9c39WtQ2mxs4ZuVbt9rGngNiihJplvoit+oB6vdriETRi9b 4W3fGzZrS3iGKueiK5VPZFGsxege40MAaOciSRJHLmZ4gkaACxAlh5w4uySMIPBmKGEChiu1yrBS h//q4+mW9ig6j1FOOh0aia0hxccRI05msuNeBa1uDvLqxYuXj56/fPT7y8ePXz76dbn2ttxllIR5 uTc/ffPP0y+dv3/78c2Tb+14kce//uWr13/8+V/qpUHru2evnz979f3Xf/38xALvcnSYhx+QGAvn Oj52brEYNmhZAB/y95M4iBDJS3STUKAEKRkLeiAjA319gSiy4HrYtOMdDunCBrw0v2cQ3o/4XBIL 8FoUG8A9xmiPceuerqm18laYJ6F9cT7P424hdGRbO9jw8mA+g7gnNpVBhA2aNym4HIU4wdJRc2yK sUXsLiGGXffIiDPBJtK5S5weIlaTHJBDI5oyocskBr8sbATB34Zt9u44PUZt6vv4yETC2UDUphJT w4yX0Fyi2MoYxTSP3EUyspHcX/CRYXAhwdMhpswZjLEQNpkbfGHQvQZpxu72PbqITSSXZGpD7iLG 8sg+mwYRimdWziSJ8tgrYgohipybTFpJMPOEqD74ASWF7r5DsOHut5/t25CG7AGiZubcdiQwM8/j gk4Qtinv8thIsV1OrNHRm4dGaO9iTNExGmPs3L5iw7OZYfOM9NUIssplbLPNVWTGquonWECtpIob i2OJMEJ2H4esgM/eYiPxLFASI16k+frUDJkBXHWxNV7paGqkUsLVobWTuCFiY3+FWm9GyAgr1Rf2 eF1ww3/vcsZA5t4HyOD3loHE/s62OUDUWCALmAMEVYYt3YKI4f5MRB0nLTa3yk3MQ5u5obxR9MQk eWsFtFH7+B+v9oEK49UPTy3Y06l37MCTVDpFyWSzvinCbVY1AeNj8ukXNX00T25iuEcs0LOa5qym +d/XNEXn+aySOatkzioZu8hHqGSy4kU/Alo96NFa4sKnPhNC6b5cULwrdNkj4OyPhzCoO1po/ZBp FkFzuZyBCznSbYcz+QWR0X6EZrBMVa8QiqXqUDgzJqBw0sNW3WqCzuM9Nk5Hq9XVc00QQDIbh8Jr NQ5lmkxHG83sAd5ave6F+kHrioCSfR8SucVMEnULieZq8C0k9M5OhUXbwqKl1Bey0F9Lr8Dl5CD1 SNz3UkYQbhDSY+WnVH7l3VP3dJExzW3XLNtrK66n42mDRC7cTBK5MIzg8tgcPmVftzOXGvSUKbZp NFsfw9cqiWzkBpqYPecYzlzdBzUjNOu4E/jJBM14BvqEylSIhknHHcmloT8ks8y4kH0kohSmp9L9 x0Ri7lASQ6zn3UCTjFu11lR7/ETJtSufnuX0V97JeDLBI1kwknVhLlVinT0hWHXYHEjvR+Nj55DO +S0EhvKbVWXAMRFybc0x4bngzqy4ka6WR9F435IdUURnEVreKPlknsJ1e00ntw/NdHNXZn+5mcNQ OenEt+7bhdRELmkWXCDq1rTnj493yedYZXnfYJWm7s1c117luqJb4uQXQo5atphBTTG2UMtGTWqn WBDklluHZtEdcdq3wWbUqgtiVVfq3taLbXZ4DyK/D9XqnEqhqcKvFo6C1SvJNBPo0VV2uS+dOScd 90HF73pBzQ9KlZY/KHl1r1Jq+d16qev79erAr1b6vdpDMIqM4qqfrj2EH/t0sXxvr8e33t3Hq1L7 3IjFZabr4LIW1u/uq7Xid/cOAcs8aNSG7Xq71yi1691hyev3WqV20OiV+o2g2R/2A7/VHj50nSMN 9rr1wGsMWqVGNQhKXqOi6LfapaZXq3W9Zrc18LoPl7aGna++V+bVvHb+BQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYA CAAAACEAddf9Xe4AAABxAQAAIAAAAHdvcmQvd2ViZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy90YXNrcGFuZXMueG1sZM/B TsMwDAbgOxLvEPlO0+4wQbV2lwmJOzxAlrqttSauYrNub08qDcTgFsfS/3/e7S9hMmdMQhwbqIoS DEbPHcWhgY/316dnMKIudm7iiA1cUWDfPj7sFtS5Vien2UUUk2Oi1OtnA6PmlbXiRwxOikA+sXCv hedgue/Jo13wiBfFuPaK/cmxm7IqbVVBe19gOvan7NBMSDSMCuZMQkeaSK8NZPVCnY75gs3LFkzi JT+/Q353Jexv1vQPyjPGvOs5Bad5TMNNe2D/GTBq1pVbm3ByurJHmiV31dRl1FtXgW139o79d5b2 CwAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEA680GBTwEAAAXDAAAEQAAAHdvcmQvc2V0dGluZ3MueG1stFZt b+I4EP5+0v0HlM9HAyGhJSpdQQu3XZXb06ar++zEDlj1S2Q7UHZ1//3GTtxAy63aXfVLa88z88xk PC9cfnjkrLclSlMppsHwbBD0iCgkpmI9Db7eL/sXQU8bJDBiUpBpsCc6+HD1+2+Xu1QTY0BN94BC 6JQX02BjTJWGoS42hCN9JisiACyl4sjAVa1DjtRDXfULyStkaE4ZNfswGgzGQUsjp0GtRNpS9Dkt lNSyNNYklWVJC9L+8xbqNX4bkxtZ1JwI4zyGijCIQQq9oZX2bPxn2QDceJLtjz5iy5nX2w0Hr/jc nVT4yeI14VmDSsmCaA0PxJkPkIrOcfyC6Mn3GfhuP9FRgflw4E6HkSdvI4heEIwLit/GMW45QrA8 4NHkbTSJp9F7Th49kWavSW0D3dFcIdUUbptXXqS3ayEVyhmEA/ntQYp6Ljr710Z8BU3zTUre26UV UQVUDnTcYBCEFoD3kmVmkAH1VFeEMdeCBSMI2HfpWiEOzeMlzgaTEtXM3KM8M7ICpS2CjziPWspi gxQqDFFZhQpgu5bCKMm8HpZ/SXMNjaigThqLDVbZBlXkpiHWV5cy1VbQetK9bUoeIWyCqYHBUFHM 0eM0iAbxxDKEpyh2aSmlEdKQv9XhDeKwBdAfNr6fid03hM9ticAvLs94jqWe5siwmT7dKWsmGZgI xOH1jqbTSmJiH6BW9PVlZg1ckodJ+xYnHUmYvIpicm+rJjN7RpbwRhn9RmYCf6q1ocDoZtQvRPCj AIiwnj9Dnd/vK7IkyNRQDe/kzBXcktFqRZWS6lZgaIF3c0bLkihwQKGlVlCJVMmdy/NHgjAsvHfy W2vyDyjDmBndQ/c9zKUxkn/cVxvI9a+9pK/lrnxhbWPXYfbwBTrlSXVws0wGyXUTqUU7JAFwMTuF XEyi+Sw6hczjZDwfn0L+389ikUQLxxY+RcpTuyZtFzYnW+493lhcI54rinoru0hDq5GrhzkVHs8J DGJyiGR17sF+vwE0R4wtIfEecEnjKaa6gpHkzmyF1LrjbTXUSSkMvk9PXHZkE/WnknXVoDuFqqaM vcowjltLKswd5V6u6zzzVgJWxwFUC/x5q1yeuvTsUgNl4cbBHXLl5XSJ6H/N2vJjKrOlQ1aoqpoK zNfDacDoemOGtmgM3DD83nKXfB21WOSwqMHcBRX2y0C7PXSyyMsO9EZeNupksZfFnSzxsqSTjb1s bGUbmDkK9twDNIM/WnkpGZM7gj92+AtRkwS3nH52W7XaDO1lbY50LWaVq2MGjAxq2z88MnYl/iwW u54LCuWY7Xnebd2zJnBGNYyOCha0kcpjfzhsGKdYFrfQSXBy8ngWLyaLyUUDJ26xGzdd4N2/kHKO NMEt5k2TxvR7EsfDm/lo1B8vzyf9OInP+7PxZNyP59H59TiZzW4uRv+2Tep/0V/9BwAA//8DAFBL AwQUAAYACAAAACEAvn5zEQcMAABxdgAADwAAAHdvcmQvc3R5bGVzLnhtbOydS3fbuhHH9z2n34FH q3aRyG8nPte5x4+49rlx4hvZzRoiIQs1Sah8+NFPXwAkJUhDUBxw6lU3iSVxfgAx8x9g+Pzt99ck Dp55lguZno52P+6MAp6GMhLp4+no4f7qw6dRkBcsjVgsU346euP56Pcvf/3Lby8nefEW8zxQgDQ/ ScLT0bwoFifjcR7OecLyj3LBU/XjTGYJK9TH7HGcsOypXHwIZbJghZiKWBRv472dnaNRjcn6UORs JkJ+KcMy4Wlh7McZjxVRpvlcLPKG9tKH9iKzaJHJkOe52ukkrngJE+kSs3sAQIkIM5nLWfFR7Uzd I4NS5rs75q8kXgEOcYA9ADgKRYRjHNWMsbK0ODnHYQ4bTP6W8NdRkIQnN4+pzNg0ViQ1NIHau8CA 9b+6sS8qOCIZXvIZK+Mi1x+zu6z+WH8y/13JtMiDlxOWh0Lcq84oYiIU/PoszcVI/cJZXpzlgrX+ ONd/tP4S5oX19bmIxGisW8z/o358ZvHpaG+v+eZC92Dtu5ilj813PP3wMLF7Yn01VdzTEcs+TM60 4bjesep/a3cXm59MwwsWCtMOmxVcxf3u0Y6GxkLLbO/wc/PhZ6kHmpWFrBsxgOr/JXYMRlzJQYlj UmlU/cpn32T4xKNJoX44HZm21JcPN3eZkJnS4enos2lTfTnhibgWUcRTa8N0LiL+a87Th5xHq+// vDJaqr8IZZmqv/ePD00UxHn09TXkC61M9WvKtE++a4NYb12KVePG/N8NbLf2RJv9nDOdnoLdTYTp Pgqxpy1ya2/bmeXGvputUA3tv1dDB+/V0OF7NXT0Xg0dv1dDn96rIYP5XzYk0oi/VkKEzQDqNo5D jWiOQ2xojkNLaI5DKmiOQwlojiPQ0RxHHKM5jjBFcAoZuqLQCvZ9R7R3c7fPEX7c7VOCH3f7DODH 3Z7w/bjb87sfd3s69+Nuz95+3O3JGs+tllrBjZJZWgxW2UzKIpUFDwr+OpzGUsUyNRsNT096PCPZ SQJMldnqiXgwLWTm8/YIMSL1n88LXdUFchbMxGOZqVJ/aMd5+sxjVXQHLIoUjxCY8aLMHCPiE9MZ n/GMpyGnDGw6qK4Eg7RMpgSxuWCPZCyeRsTD1xBJksIyoFX9PNciEQRBnbAwk8O7JhlZfvgm8uFj pSHBeRnHnIj1nSbEDGt4bWAww0sDgxleGRjM8MLA8hnVENU0opGqaUQDVtOIxq2KT6pxq2lE41bT iMatpg0ft3tRxCbF26uO3f7H7i5iqY+yD+7HRDymTC0Ahk839THT4I5l7DFji3mgj0q3Y+19xrZz LqO34J5iTluSqNb1JkQu1F6LtBw+oGs0KnEteUTyWvKIBLbkDZfYrVom6wXaNU09MymnRatoDamX aCcsLqsF7XC1sWJ4hK0EcCWynEwG7ViCCP6ul7PanRSZb9XL4R1bsYbLajMrkXavRhL0MpbhE00a vn5b8EyVZU+DSVcyjuULj+iIkyKTVazZkt8zLukl+a/JYs5yYWqlNUT/qb45Px/cssXgHbqLmUhp /Pb1Q8JEHNCtIK7vb78F93Khy0w9MDTAc1kUMiFj1kcC//aLT/9O08EzVQSnb0R7e0Z0eMjALgTB JFORZEREUstMkQqSOdTw/uBvU8myiIZ2l/HqkpiCExEnLFlUiw4Cbam8+KLyD8FqyPD+yTKhjwtR ieqeBGYdNszL6b94ODzVfZcByZGhH2Vhjj+apa6xpsMNXyas4YYvEYw31fSg45dgZ9dww3d2DUe1 sxcxy3PhPIXqzaPa3YZHvb/Di7+aJ2OZzcqYbgAbINkINkCyIZRxmaQ55R4bHuEOGx71/hKGjOER HJIzvH9kIiJzhoFRecLAqNxgYFQ+MDBSBwy/QseCDb9Mx4INv1anghEtASwYVZyRTv9EZ3ksGFWc GRhVnBkYVZwZGFWc7V8GfDZTi2C6KcZCUsWchaSbaNKCJwuZseyNCPk15o+M4ABpRbvL5EzfKyHT 6iJuAqQ+Rh0TLrYrHJWTf/EpWdc0i7JfBEdEWRxLSXRsbTXhGMv1a9e2mZk7OQZ34S5mIZ/LOOKZ Y5/ctqpenlS3ZWx233Sj12HPb+JxXgST+fJov4052tlq2RTsa2bbG2wb86PmfpY2s1seiTJpOgpv pjja729sInrN+GC78WolsWZ52NMStnm03XK1Sl6zPO5pCdv81NPS6HTNsksPlyx7ag2E4674WdZ4 juA77oqipXFrs12BtLRsC8Hjrihak0pwFob6bAH0Tj/NuO37icdtj1GRm4KRk5vSW1duRJfAfvJn oWd2TNI07S2vngB53yyie2XOP0tZHbdfO+HU/6auG7VwSnMetHL2+5+4Wssy7nHsnW7ciN55x43o nYDciF6ZyGmOSkluSu/c5Eb0TlJuBDpbwRkBl62gPS5bQXufbAUpPtlqwCrAjei9HHAj0EKFCLRQ B6wU3AiUUIG5l1AhBS1UiEALFSLQQoULMJxQoT1OqNDeR6iQ4iNUSEELFSLQQoUItFAhAi1UiEAL 1XNt7zT3EiqkoIUKEWihQgRaqGa9OECo0B4nVGjvI1RI8REqpKCFChFooUIEWqgQgRYqRKCFChEo oQJzL6FCClqoEIEWKkSghVrdaugvVGiPEyq09xEqpPgIFVLQQoUItFAhAi1UiEALFSLQQoUIlFCB uZdQIQUtVIhACxUi0EI1JwsHCBXa44QK7X2ECik+QoUUtFAhAi1UiEALFSLQQoUItFAhAiVUYO4l VEhBCxUi0EKFiK74rE9Rui6z38Uf9XResd//1FXdqZ/2rdw2ar8/qumVm9X/XoRzKZ+C1hsP9029 0Q8iprGQ5hC147S6zTWXRKBOfP646L7Dx6YPfOhSfS+EOWcK4Ad9LcExlYOukLctQZF30BXptiVY dR50ZV/bEkyDB11J1+iyuShFTUfAuCvNWMa7DvOubG2ZwyHuytGWIRzhrsxsGcIB7srHluFhoJPz pvVhz3E6Wl5fCghd4WgRjt2ErrCEvmrSMRRGX6e5CX295yb0daObgPKnE4N3rBuF9rAb5edqKDOs q/2F6iZgXQ0JXq4GGH9XQ5S3qyHKz9UwMWJdDQlYV/snZzfBy9UA4+9qiPJ2NUT5uRpOZVhXQwLW 1ZCAdfXACdmJ8Xc1RHm7GqL8XA0Xd1hXQwLW1ZCAdTUkeLkaYPxdDVHeroYoP1eDKhntakjAuhoS sK6GBC9XA4y/qyHK29UQ1eVqcxRlzdUoD1vmuEWYZYibkC1DXHK2DD2qJcvas1qyCJ7VEvRV43Nc tWQ7zU3o6z03oa8b3QSUP50YvGPdKLSH3Sg/V+OqpTZX+wvVTcC6GlctOV2Nq5Y6XY2rljpdjauW 3K7GVUttrsZVS22u9k/OboKXq3HVUqercdVSp6tx1ZLb1bhqqc3VuGqpzdW4aqnN1QMnZCfG39W4 aqnT1bhqye1qXLXU5mpctdTmaly11OZqXLXkdDWuWup0Na5a6nQ1rlpyuxpXLbW5GlcttbkaVy21 uRpXLTldjauWOl2Nq5Y6XY2rlm6ViSB4BNQkYVkR0D0v7prl84INfzjhQ5rxXMbPPArQuzp+WXtn lW7DvGFObV+oHdWPLbfuMYqqx7bWQLPhTbR8t5Q21j0K6rd41V+bjtfnWKsWjSFsKpyrtsL6gVOO puoHxy7vfDKPjd1s2PF0WdORVdQ0W9dDuxqvaru10ersd6GjtKPPJoo7x6gKdFcHP9fK3dZD1Z9p XL3nTP1xk0YK8FK/46vqafTKKpT6/YLH8S2rtpYL96YxnxXVr7s75jkDG79Pq0fmOe0zk1udgPF6 Z6qP9bvWHONdPUS/PunvDEmdQFqG21yBMnSk3X1bk8uyN/VTZTd7U788oxpGptA/tKiBdnSyab6v SBdKKdv2oSU8slzomDCb7excXh3uHF5UG9evx1ORbFKA+r/ZTufbSpELmeu58FM9AVjbGBcvN/m8 X13qpl1Z88Br9+yX7h0sPzhfutcnYYRlruLQpLHNYLAGbdMF1U/BakA3/NCabxxe2eYR1/Bjo+mq elnK5q7U71DBRFNF+n80oaLJGrRNF1Q/DY2m2r+Do6n5K//yXwAAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAh ABuSEMjFAQAAiwUAABIAAAB3b3JkL2ZvbnRUYWJsZS54bWzcktuK2zAQhu8LfQeh+41lJ85uzTpL DxsolF4s2wdQFNkW1cFolHjz9h3JTloaFtY3vagNQvpn5hvpZ+4fXowmR+lBOVvTfMEokVa4vbJt TX88b2/uKIHA7Z5rZ2VNTxLow+b9u/uhapwNQLDeQmVETbsQ+irLQHTScFi4XloMNs4bHvDo28xw //PQ3whneh7UTmkVTlnB2JpOGP8WimsaJeQXJw5G2pDqMy81Ep2FTvVwpg1voQ3O73vvhATANxs9 8gxX9oLJV1cgo4R34JqwwMdMN0ooLM9Z2hn9G1DOAxRXgLVQ+3mM9cTIsPIPDsh5mPKMgZORL5QY UX1trfN8p5GE1hB8HUnguMZmm2k2yFBZbjDrM9dq51UK9Nw6kDnGjlzXlBVsy0pc479iy7jSLCaK jnuQETImslFuuFH6dFZhUABjoFdBdGf9yL2KNxxDoFoMHGDHavrIGCs+brd0VHK8XVRWt58mpYi9 0vdhUpYXhUVFJE465iNHJM4lB3tmowNXTjwrI4F8lwN5cobbVxwp2BqdKNGP6MxyliM+cWc78vi3 I7d35T9xZJoN8k21XXh1QuJc/KcTMm1g8wsAAP//AwBQSwMEFAAGAAgAAAAhAPJnFu/jAQAAeAYA ABMACAFkb2NQcm9wcy9jdXN0b20ueG1sIKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAtJXNjtsgFIX3lfoOFntiIHaMoyTTTH6qSJN2pKRddBNhfD1BtcEyJDNp1Xcv0TQdeVlX3oGA w3fgcpjcvVRlcIbGKqOniA4ICkBLkyv9NEVf9mvMUWCd0LkojYYpuoBFd7P37yaPjamhcQps4CW0 naKjc/U4DK08QiXswA9rP1KYphLOd5un0BSFkrA08lSBdiEjZBTKk3WmwvVfOfSqNz67rpK5kVc6 +3V/qb3ebPJH/BIUlVP5FP1cxovlMiYxZqt0gSmh9zgdpgkmnBB2zxbrdL76hYL6OpmhQIvKW9/u No+HB5FBeSgiJsQwYpgnZIQjxjnOckoxZBmP0zQmjMvDSoushNzvf3bjsn62rpntmxNMwrf+JLyx /SflsCvlTjnYtCETVqScZwXmo4LiiIoCp1RkmOWJzAmleRYlvZiIupr4/KyhaXn4rrLGV235oVKy MdYUbiBN1Qt13PnowS2FgxY3I5RjQjEje0LGNBpH8YCMIr+IfOuFftSV/pNf1UL/CP4SRNkLZdKV cl7XpZLC+XhrwW5vZRHMf5waCDb6NVX8vMCHhwN5bfbihXcOlBcHOof8sN2t94ctuKNpP9z5yUep 9yB74U5v3DvQVjl1Vu7yLwUQvn0Zs98AAAD//wMAUEsDBBQABgAIAAAAIQATAEHW1AEAANkDAAAQ AAgBZG9jUHJvcHMvYXBwLnhtbCCiBAEooAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAJxT y27bMBC8F+g/CLzHlJwiCAyaQeGgyKFtDFhJziy1kolSJEFujLhf35UUK3SbU3SafQ1nHxI3L70t DhCT8W7NqkXJCnDaN8Z1a/ZQf7u4ZkVC5RplvYM1O0JiN/LzJ7GNPkBEA6kgCpfWbI8YVpwnvYde pQWFHUVaH3uFZMaO+7Y1Gm69fu7BIV+W5RWHFwTXQHMRZkI2Ma4O+FHSxutBX3qsj4H4pKihD1Yh yJ9DpV00HnvBZ6+oPSpbmx7k5TX5Z0tsVQdJVoJPQDz52CR5KfgExGavotJIA5QVVWam+BqCNVoh TVb+MDr65Fss7ke5xVAueJ4iqIUd6Odo8ChLwXNTfDdukjEBkhVVF1XYv2qbLbHTysKGmpetsgkE f3OIO1DDYrfKDPoOuDqARh+LZP7Qapes+KUSDCNbs4OKRjlkU9pkjNiGhFHWBi1xz/YI87Qcmy+D yAmcJ47GqIHwubrxhXTfUm/4jtgqFztqmKRmcnJlpzf+Yd34PihH8+UzogH/Tg+h9rfDYbzO8NyZ Lf3J4H4XlKadLMt8/VlA7MgLDe1zXsnsEHfUQLQDPdW6DppTzv+B4aAepz9VVleLkr7xgk4+uoP5 F5J/AQAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAUlpNtXUBAADrAgAAEQAIAWRvY1Byb3BzL2NvcmUueG1s IKIEASigAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAjJJdT8IwFIbvTfwPS++3dpsaXMZI 0HCjJCZiNN7V9gCVtWvawuDf220wXOTCu/PxnLenb5tP9rIMdmCsqNQYxRFBAShWcaFWY/S2mIUj FFhHFadlpWCMDmDRpLi+ypnOWGXgxVQajBNgA6+kbMb0GK2d0xnGlq1BUht5QvnmsjKSOp+aFdaU begKcELIHZbgKKeO4kYw1L0iOkpy1kvqrSlbAc4wlCBBOYvjKMZn1oGR9uJA2/lFSuEOGi6ip2ZP 763owbquozptUb9/jD/mz6/tVUOhGq8YoCLnLHPClVDk+Bz6yG6/voG5rtwnPmYGqKtM8SRkMDXe 8bJFTuXG8A0c6spw64cHmcc4WGaEdv4ZO+lBwdMltW7u33UpgE8Pg1P+dpsBAzvR/IoiaYk+zY8W d5sBD7w1WWfkqfOePjwuZqhISDwKSRzG94skzW5vMkI+m+UG82dBeVzgH4oJWRCSpclQ8STQ+TP8 nsUPAAAA//8DAFBLAwQUAAYACAAAACEAvdSNvycBAACPAgAAFAAAAHdvcmQvd2ViU2V0dGluZ3Mu eG1slNLNagIxEADge6HvEHLXrFKlLK5CKZZeSqHtA8TsrIZmMiETu9qnb9xqf/DiXkImyXzJhJkt dujEB0S25Cs5GhZSgDdUW7+u5NvrcnArBSfta+3IQyX3wHIxv76atWULqxdIKZ9kkRXPJZpKblIK pVJsNoCahxTA582GIuqUw7hWqOP7NgwMYdDJrqyzaa/GRTGVRyZeolDTWAP3ZLYIPnX5KoLLInne 2MAnrb1EaynWIZIB5lwPum8PtfU/zOjmDEJrIjE1aZiLOb6oo3L6qOhm6H6BST9gfAZMja37GdOj oXLmH4ehHzM5MbxH2EmBpnxce4p65bKUv0bk6kQHH8bDZfPcIRSSRfsJS4p3kVqGqA7L2jlqn58e cqD+tdH8CwAA//8DAFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQCKe3jjqQEAAJQIAAATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA AABbQ29udGVudF9UeXBlc10ueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAKcE/c4kAQAAeAMAAAsAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAA4gMAAF9yZWxzLy5yZWxzUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhAM/a/yolAQAAOQUAABwAAAAAAAAA AAAAAAAANwcAAHdvcmQvX3JlbHMvZG9jdW1lbnQueG1sLnJlbHNQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAi+lB mQ0DAADPCgAAEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACeCQAAd29yZC9kb2N1bWVudC54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAA ACEAUBhXF4YCAACiCgAAEgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADaDAAAd29yZC9mb290bm90ZXMueG1sUEsBAi0A FAAGAAgAAAAhANjmjl5HAgAAEgkAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAkA8AAHdvcmQvZm9vdGVyMS54bWxQ SwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEATYLKfUkCAAASCQAAEAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFEgAAd29yZC9oZWFkZXIx LnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQD8BTPJhgIAAJwKAAARAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHwUAAB3b3JkL2Vu ZG5vdGVzLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQB/AYygwAAAABwBAAArAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADEXAAB3 b3JkL3dlYmV4dGVuc2lvbnMvX3JlbHMvdGFza3BhbmVzLnhtbC5yZWxzUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAh AEfYNNQyAQAALQIAACQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAOhgAAHdvcmQvd2ViZXh0ZW5zaW9ucy93ZWJleHRl bnNpb24xLnhtbFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQC29GeY0gYAAMkgAAAVAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAK4ZAAB3 b3JkL3RoZW1lL3RoZW1lMS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAddf9Xe4AAABxAQAAIAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAACzIAAAd29yZC93ZWJleHRlbnNpb25zL3Rhc2twYW5lcy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEA 680GBTwEAAAXDAAAEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADfIQAAd29yZC9zZXR0aW5ncy54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYA CAAAACEAvn5zEQcMAABxdgAADwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABKJgAAd29yZC9zdHlsZXMueG1sUEsBAi0A FAAGAAgAAAAhABuSEMjFAQAAiwUAABIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAfjIAAHdvcmQvZm9udFRhYmxlLnht bFBLAQItABQABgAIAAAAIQDyZxbv4wEAAHgGAAATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHM0AABkb2NQcm9wcy9j dXN0b20ueG1sUEsBAi0AFAAGAAgAAAAhABMAQdbUAQAA2QMAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAjzcAAGRv Y1Byb3BzL2FwcC54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAUlpNtXUBAADrAgAAEQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACZ OgAAZG9jUHJvcHMvY29yZS54bWxQSwECLQAUAAYACAAAACEAvdSNvycBAACPAgAAFAAAAAAAAAAA AAAAAABFPQAAd29yZC93ZWJTZXR0aW5ncy54bWxQSwUGAAAAABMAEwD2BAAAnj4AAAAA";

                context.document.body.insertFileFromBase64(documentData, "start");

                return context.sync();
            });
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        if (error instanceof window.OfficeExtension.Error) {
            // console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
        }
    });
}
```

***Note***: You can quickly and easily try this snippet yourself (and verify that it works on both Desktop and in Word Online) by using Script Lab (https://aka.ms/getscriptlab). Simply install the Script Lab add-in (free), then choose "Import" in the navigation menu, and use the following Gist URL: https://gist.github.com/kbrandl/8b747983dab42bdff0430d0af428b89e.